# QAudioDeviceInfo finds no default audio device on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt5, qtmultimedia

I am trying to run the basic example from the [QAudioDeviceInfo class reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qaudiodeviceinfo.html), but Qt is not finding a default audio device.

Running this code shows no output:

```
foreach (const QAudioDeviceInfo &deviceInfo,  QAudioDeviceInfo::availableDevices(QAudio::AudioOutput))
    qDebug() << "Device name: " << deviceInfo.deviceName();
```

I'm running Qt Creator 2.7.1 with Qt 5.0.2 on Ubuntu 13.10. Qt Multimedia was installed via `apt-get`. My pro file has `QT += multimedia`. My header file includes:

```
#include <QAudio>
#include <QAudioOutput>
#include <QAudioDeviceInfo>
```

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I found the fix for my answer, although apparently I can't answer my own question until tomorrow. I just had to run:

`sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5-plugins`

Answer (score 18):

It was fixed with a simple command:

`sudo apt-get install libqt5multimedia5-plugins`

Qt Multimedia requires this plugin package for audio backend support.

Comment: For OS X deployment, this is the `plugins/audio/libqtaudio_coreaudio.dylib` file.

Comment: This is also true for Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Solved also my problem with PyQt5 on Ubuntu 14.04 :)

Answer (score 3):

Had same issue in windows. Fixed it by replacing `Qt5Multimedia.dll` in `\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt*` with one from `\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin`.

Spend some time finding solution so decided to leave it here.